# Ideas for bushes or shrubs greater than 6 feet that will grow in partial shade against a building in Zone 2-3?

Tags: shrubs, hardiness-zone

I have a narrow garden bed at the back of my carriage garage made out of retaining wall.  It is directly against my building.

I would like to find a bush, hedge or similar that will grow in this shady area, ideally eventually become over 6 feet tall to blend the building face into the landscape (primarily for neighbour benefit). I live in Zone 3.

Any suggestions of some robust hardy bushes that might be up to the task and thrive in this challenging environ?

Comment: How wide can the plants get - you say 'narrow' but don't say how wide. A photo or two of the area would be useful

Comment: Spencer, what do you mean directly against your building?  The back wall of this bed?  Anything against the structure of your building is a very bad thing.  It will hold moisture and ruin your siding.  Please add more information about this and suggestions will be forthcoming.  But there is a red flag when you say it is ON your siding?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  We have approximately 36 inches of soil between the side of the building and the retaining wall.  We have 15 feet in width to play with.  The siding is concrete hardy plank so I'm not super worried about a little contact or moisture.  I of course am worried about deep rooted species like alder or similar and wouldn't want to plan those.

It may be that its too narrow of a space.  However its a big blank wall and some green would really help but would have to be something a little non-conventional.

Answer (score 3):

Red Twig Dogwood, depending on how much light. They can make a thicket.

Comment: I like this suggestion.  Any of the varieties of Cornus stolonifera would do well!